# Скрыть элемент списка RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Мне нужно скрыть один из элементов в RecyclerView с последующим его восстановлением. Может кто с таким сталкивался?

Описание ситуации: У меня есть список, из n-го количества элементов. Нужно удалить элемент списка с возможностью его восстановления в ближайшие несколько секунд. Я хочу скрывать элемент списка и если его удаление не отменится удалить вовсе, в ином случае восстановить видимость.

Можно конечно использовать какой-то буфер, в него класть этот самый элемент и если его удаление отменят восстанавливать обратно. Как по мне такое решение лишено изящности и скорее всего не совсем верное.

Вот как оно выглядит у меня (код в адаптере):

```
private lateinit var bufferPreDeleteElement: Alarm
fun toBuffer(position: Int){
    bufferPreDeleteElement = list[position]
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

fun fromBuffer(position: Int){
    list.add(position, bufferPreDeleteElement)
    notifyItemInserted(position)
}
```

Второй вариант присваивать нужному элементу значение View.GONE. Но не могу понять как пробиться к элементам из вне и нужно же учитывать факт переиспользования контейнеров, что-то не совсем представляю как оно себя будет вести.

Comment: как [получить доступ к View айтемов из активити](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35428735/7566397)

Comment: Спасибо, претендует на самое изящное решение layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position).visibility = View.GONE

Comment: если вы самостоятельно нашли решение вашей проблемы, оформите его, как ответ (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). это поможет другим людям с аналогичной проблемой решить ее быстрее

Comment: Спасибо, но это ссылка на варианты ответов предложена вами. Потому Ответ скорее подсказали вы чем я его сам нашел.